# Quantum algorithm writing

Tags: quantum-computation

I'm interested in learning to write quantum algorithms, but I don't know where to start. Could someone recommend some resources for me?

Comment: The classic text: http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Computation-Information-10th-Anniversary/dp/1107002176/

Comment: That text that Simon linked is the standard; if you're looking for something shorter, this article presents a handful of quantum algorithms: http://www.du.edu/nsm/departments/mathematics/media/documents/preprints/m0310.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Both of those resources look great. I've already started reading the linked article.